# ExactTarget REST vs SOAP API

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap, rest

I'm impressed with ExactTarget's REST API; it's well considered, particularly its oAuth implementation.

However, the services available in the REST API only provides a handful of core methods. The REST API is not as extensive as SOAP and doesn't include any of the methods we need, so we're stuck using SOAP, which is unfortunate as we're building an app in Node.js and would prefer to  use RESTful requests.

Can someone clarify if there are plans to extend service and method support in the ExactTarget REST API to make it match the SOAP API?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes - we are planning to extend all functionality of the REST services provided by the Fuel API, and bring it to parity with the SOAP API.

Comment: That's good to hear. Is there a timeframe for this?

Comment: Possibly, but I am not aware of what the exact time frame is.